# Mysql Advance query - Date Range Table to result per day columns

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-range

I got a challenge here.

I have a table that looks like this.

```
| DayDate    |EndDate    |  Rate  | 
-----------------------------------
| 2013-07-01 |2013-08-05 | 200.00 | 
| 2013-08-06 |2013-10-20 | 150.00 | 
| 2013-10-21 |2013-12-31 | 130.00 |
```

I like to run a query which should return with daily rate value for given range of dates.
For example, I like to query the rates per day starting from 2013-08-03 to 2013-08-08 and the expected result should be something like the following.

```
|   From    |   To      |  Day 1  |  Day 2  |  Day 3  |  Day 4  |  Day 5  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2013-08-03 |2013-08-08 | 200.00  |  200.00 |  150.00 |  150.00 |  150.00 |
```

The number of days adding to the column will not exceed more than 30 days in my scope of the project, normally will range between 3 to 10 days in average. I would like to see some cool ideas and efficient way of generating a result like the one above.

#### update

To avoid confusion on the day columns, the day columns is to be generated by the query for the number of days between the search period.

Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: @JohnConde I tried the usual ways but was thinking if this is possible with mysql? so in away, i have not tried to produce this result yet, as I am lost in doing the query to add columns by dates in a range

Comment: To keep it dynamic, you are looking for a pivot, which is not natively supported by MySQL.
You can emulate with something similar to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table, but you will have null columns for your values out of range (let's say columns from Day 6 to Day 30 would show null in your example)

Comment: @AHocevar May be you got it wrong, the Day columns will be added dynamically within the queried date range. Null will be given if there are no rates stored in the table for a given date range.

Comment: I might have misunderstood; if you specify a range of 5 days (as in your example), you would have to manually adapt the number of columns in your query (or generate it dynamically with your code) rather than having a unique query adapting itself.

Comment: @AHocevar yeah, I agree to your point where generating the columns within the code or manually specifying the columns, which would work.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you have a static calendar table, containing one column DAY_DT and one row per date.
I called it CAL_DAY in my example, since it is the same name we use in our datawarehouse.

With the following query, you simply add new MAX() columns in the main query, and more CASE statements to expand your query to reflect a bigger range.

```
SELECT MAX(MIN_DAY_DT), 
  MAX(MAX_DAY_DT), 
  MAX(D1) AS "Day 1",
  MAX(D2) AS "Day 2",
  MAX(D3) AS "Day 3",
  MAX(D4) AS "Day 4",
  MAX(D5) AS "Day 5"
FROM(
  SELECT cmin.DAY_DT AS MIN_DAY_DT,
    cmax.DAY_DT AS MAX_DAY_DT,
    CASE WHEN cd.DAY_DT = cmin.DAY_DT + 1 THEN rt.Rate ELSE 0 END AS "D1",
    CASE WHEN cd.DAY_DT = cmin.DAY_DT + 2 THEN rt.Rate ELSE 0 END AS "D2",
    CASE WHEN cd.DAY_DT = cmin.DAY_DT + 3 THEN rt.Rate ELSE 0 END AS "D3",
    CASE WHEN cd.DAY_DT = cmin.DAY_DT + 4 THEN rt.Rate ELSE 0 END AS "D4",
    CASE WHEN cd.DAY_DT = cmin.DAY_DT + 5 THEN rt.Rate ELSE 0 END AS "D5"
FROM CAL_DAY cd
  JOIN CAL_DAY cmin
    ON (cd.DAY_DT >= cmin.DAY_DT)
  JOIN CAL_DAY cmax
    ON (cd.DAY_DT <= cmax.DAY_DT)
  LEFT JOIN RateTable rt ON
    (cd.DAY_DT BETWEEN rt.DayDate AND rt.EndDate)
WHERE cmin.DAY_DT = '2013-08-03' 
  AND cmax.DAY_DT = '2013-08-08')
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but MySQL is giving me SQL syntax error  near 'CASE AS "D1", CASE WHEN cd.DAY_DT = cmin.DAY_DT + 2 THEN rt.Rate ELSE 0 END' and STR_TO_DATE() function is invalid and I think just having the date value as string without that function will work fine. I am not good in using CASE in mysql, but I think the syntax error is when using END CASE